# How to disable SSLv3 on R-Shiny-server 1.4

Tags: linux, ssl, https

First I'm quite puzzled to discover today, that after exactly one year (and one day) of POODLE attack being around, Shiny-server (installed 3 weeks ago) is still shipping with SSLv3 enabled by default...

So, simple question (I of course contacted R-Shiny support, and I'm still waiting for their answer, so I'm posting here, just in case someone know about it), how to disable this on the pro version, if only possible ?

Here are some infos :

```
# cat /etc/*-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

# yum info shiny-server
Installed Packages
Name        : shiny-server
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.4.0.641
Release     : 1

# uname -a
Linux 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 15 15:05:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks !

Comment: I assume you have the required certificate already created?

Comment: Yes of course.
It use to work properly.
It's just a security hazard.

Comment: Given the documentation that exist is absolutely horrible its not all that shocking you can't figure out how to do it.  Can you supply the instructions on how to enable authentication in the first place?

Comment: "The Shiny Server Professional RPM binaries link to version 0.9.8 of the openssl and libcrypo shared libraries. On RedHat systems the shared library files have a suffix of ".6" (e.g. libcrypo.so.6) whereas on SLES they have a suffix of "0.9.8". As a result you should soft-link the existing 0.9.8 shared libraries to a version with a .6 suffix by running the following commands:" this means if you compile OpenSSL without SSL3 support you can achieve what you want.  How you accomplish that is well documented.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, I'm gonna try this.
As for authentication, well it's not about authentication, but encryption on https.
And that is easily done by adding :
`listen 443;`
and
`ssl key certificate;` in `/etc/shiny/shiny-server.conf `